# Using Win32api to print to printer

Tags: python, winapi, csv, openoffice.org

I'm trying to get a python script of mine to print a CSV file to the printer via Win32api.ShellExectute, I.E.

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0,"print","C:\Test.csv",None,".",0)
```

Here's my problem: when I associate the file with Open Office, it just completely refuses to print. Prints fine in notepad. Prints fine in Microsoft Excel. Refuses to print in Open Office.

There's no error message, either. If anyone knows a way to get an error message or SOMETHING at least I could try to work on it. I went to OpenOffice.org's website and their wiki and all of their solutions are involving their integrated python macro scripting using the UNO module. I'm looking to call the print from a seperate application.

Comment: What happens when you do this from the shell itself? I predict that won't work either.

Comment: @Adam, since the example is claimed to work in Notepad and Excel I'd assume it's just a typo.

Comment: When I try to execute it from the shell it says "Unable to initialize device PRN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on the shell defining a "print" verb for a particular file type. This works as follows:

1. The shell strips off the file extension, in this case ".csv".
2. The shell looks up the extension in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to find the associated file type. On my system for example this is "Excel.CSV".
3. Under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filetype there will be a "shell" key, and under that are the supported verbs.
4. The registry entry under the verb will contain details on how to run a command to produce the desired action.

All of those registry keys must be placed there by an installation program. When you associate a file type, you're changing the lookup in step 2.

**Edit:** What I left unsaid is that there's nothing to prevent you from correcting the ommision of a verb from a specific file type, as long as you can edit the registry and provide an appropriate command line.

Comment: @eryksun, I never knew about those command line queries - thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys I knew there was probably a way to edit how the shell handled it but I'm not too familiar with using the registry. I do have one question, though: When I look, for example, under Excel.CSV/shell/print/command, I see one entry for the filepath of the excel executable, and then I see a "command" entry, but in the value I get this:        "w_1^VW!!!!!!!!!MKKSkEXCELFiles>tW{~$4Q]c@II=l2xaTO5 /e" How do I decipher this? I was expecting a list of commands like "print" etc. that I could use in the ShellExecute(). Also, how would I go about adding a .CSV entry to the openoffice registry?